# Publish message after filtering subscribed topic

Tags: ros, pcl, callback, ros-kinetic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I want to subscribe to a PointCloud topic, filter it and publish it later on a different topic in real time. What I have so far is this:

```
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);   //TODO: Avoid global variables. Is there another way?

 void subCallback(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr& input){
  pcl::copyPointCloud(*input,*cloud);
  std::cerr<<"Cloud size is "<< cloud->points.size()<<std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){

      ros::init(argc, argv, "plane_extraction");


      //Necessary pointclouds
      pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>),
                                          cloud_projected (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>),
                                          cloud_p (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>),
                                          cloud_f (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
      std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > results;


      //Only one Node Handle for both subscribing and publishing
      ros::NodeHandle nh;

      //Publishers array (one for each topic). Each topic represents a segmented plane

      std::vector<ros::Publisher> publishers;

      while(ros::ok()){

            sub=nh.subscribe("/camera/depth/points", 5, subCallback);

           /*Filters and stuff
           ******************
           ******************
           ******************
           ******************/

            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
              publishers[j].publish(results[j]);
              std:cerr<<"There are "<<j<<" publishers"<<std::endl;
            }
            ros::spinOnce();
      }

      return(0);

}
```

I don't know if the while(ros::ok()) spinOnce() is incorrect or what, but I don't find the way to do it. The message inside the callback appears randomly, and when it does, it gets stuck there, as if it never left the callback.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284936/publish-message-after-filtering-subscribed-topic/) by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
As `Cerin` mentioned, you don't need to put `nh.subscribe("/camera/depth/points", 5, subCallback); in the` while `loop`. Because, it uses to make subscriber object, so you just need to do it in initialization of your `main` function.

Your call back function is called whenever your subscribed topic is updated. Otherwise, it will not be called.

You can publish your new `topic` in a `while` loop but it can be updated only when your callback function is called. You can use a `global variable` to save and modify your data and publish it either in the `while` loop or `callback function.` I have attached a simple example here. Hope this will help you.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include <gayan2Dmapping/gayan2Dmappingmsgs.h> 
#include <gayan2Dmapping/fakemsg.h>
#include <gayan2Dmapping/processedscan.h>
#include <sstream>


ros::Publisher pub_processedscan;
ros::Subscriber scanSub;

double x=0,y=0,z=0,theta=0;
double scanx[640],scany[640];
    
void processLaserScan(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan){
    
    x = scan->ranges[320]; 

    float sizenum_ranges = scan->ranges.size(); 
    ROS_INFO("Range[%f], #[%f]",x,sizenum_ranges);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------   
    gayan2Dmapping::processedscan msg;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<640;++i){
        if(i<320){
            int n=320-i;
            scanx[i]=(scan->ranges[i])*cos(n*scan->angle_increment);
            scany[i]=(scan->ranges[i])*sin(n*scan->angle_increment);
                        
        }
        else {
            int n=-320+i;
            scanx[i]=(scan->ranges[i])*cos(n*scan->angle_increment);
            scany[i]=(scan->ranges[i])*sin(-n*scan->angle_increment);
            
        }
    }
    
}



void publishprocessedscan(){
    gayan2Dmapping::processedscan msg;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<640;++i){
        msg.processedscan[i]=scanx[i];
        msg.processedscany[i]=scany[i];
    }
    pub_processedscan.publish(msg);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "gayan2Dmapping");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
    

    scanSub=n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/scan",1000,processLaserScan);
    pub_processedscan = n.advertise<gayan2Dmapping::processedscan>("processedscan", 1000);
    
    while(ros::ok()){
                
                ros::spinOnce();
                loop_rate.sleep();  
                publishprocessedscan();
    }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georgee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32202/georgee/) on 2018-03-10**:
Thank you. That was absolutely precise and effective. It works now!